# Selecting vertices and moving them (Processing 3 for Android)

Tags: android, geometry, processing, transformation, vertices

I am looking for tips and hints on "the best way" to approach something. I want to either import, or create, geometry (initially a cylinder), isolate half of it, and move the vertices around, then export it again as an .obj or .stl. I realise there are libraries that will do this but I need this to work on Android and the libraries (as far as I know) don't. I made these images in 3DMax to explain what I mean. I can handle much of the coding, BUT the geometry mathematics I just cannot get my head around.

[image: Starting shape]

[image: Post-transform]

I have adapted this method for creating a cylinder from an example in the book: Processing 2: Creative Coding Hotshot...

```
float[][] vertx;
float[][] verty;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600, P3D);   

  vertx = new float[36][36];//36 triangle strips, 36 vertices
  verty = new float[36][36];
}

void draw() {
  hint( ENABLE_DEPTH_TEST );
  pushMatrix();
  background(125);
  fill(255);
  strokeWeight(0.5);

  translate( width/2, height/2, 200);
  rotateX(radians(-45));
  scale( 1 );

  translate(0, -50, 0);

  initPoints();

  beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP );
  for ( int h = 1; h < 36; h++) {
    for ( int a = 0; a<37; a++ ) {
      int aa = a % 36;
     // normal( vertx[h][aa], 0, verty[h][aa]);
      vertex( vertx[h][aa], h*5.0, verty[h][aa] );
      //normal( vertx[h-1][aa], 0, verty[h-1][aa]);
      vertex( vertx[h-1][aa], (h-1)*5.0, verty[h-1][aa] );
    }
  }
  endShape();

  beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN); //bottom
  int h = 35;
  vertex( 0, h*5, 0 );
  for ( int a = 0; a<37; a++ ) {
    int aa = a % 36;    
    vertex( vertx[h][aa], h*5, verty[h][aa] );
  }
  endShape();

  popMatrix();
  hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
}

float getR( float a, float h ) {
  float r = 50;
  return r;
}

void initPoints() {
  for ( int h = 0; h < 36; h++) {
    for ( int a = 0; a<36; a++) {
      float r = getR( a*10.0, h*5.0 ); //a = 10 (360/36)
      vertx[h][a] = cos( radians( a*10.0 )) * r;
      verty[h][a] = sin( radians( a*10.0 )) * r;
    }
  }
}
```

...and I am assuming it is possible to isolate/grab certain vertices from the array?

Any other approaches, or any advice on how to develop this? Is the import > transform method even possible? @Spektre - might there be a better approach than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very general question, so I'll give you a general answer.

Your first step is to really digest the code you posted: what do each of the calls to `vertex()` do? Where is each vertex being placed? You should be able to write your own code that draws a cylinder without copy-pasting anything from this code. You should be able to draw other shapes. Start by only drawing a few vertexes to see where they're showing up, then add a few more, then a few more, until you understand exactly what this code is doing.

There are a ton of tutorials that can help you understand the code. [Here](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshape/) is a 2D tutorial to get you started (read (and **understand**) that one first), and [here](https://processing.org/tutorials/p3d/) is a 3D version.

Once you have that working it should be pretty easy to manipulate the vertexes however you want. If you want the user to be able to select a vertex, google something like "3d point picking" for a ton of resources.

Finally, I'm not sure Processing provides an easy way to export a .obj file. But again, google is your friend- try googling something like "Processing export obj file" for a handful of libraries that seem to help with your goal.

If you get stuck on a specific step, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a specific question. Good luck!

Comment: It is quiet a general question, yes. Thank you for your answer. I do understand the basics of how it works. I am using this code because there is an .stl export function that goes with it and I stripped out to post here because I needed a tip on how to approach grabbing the vertices.

To concede to the general point you are making, yes I am keen to get on to the "meat" of what I am trying to do, but I do need to go a couple of steps backwards first. Thanks.